# A question in measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question

I found a question in a measure theory book which is as follows:

If $\mu$ is a measure on $X$ and $A\subset X$,then $\lambda:X\to [0,\infty]$ defined by $\lambda(E)=\mu(E\cap A)$ is a measure on $X$.

But I doubt whether this question is correct.First of all there is no specification of the underlying $\sigma$-algebra and $\lambda$ is given from $X\to [0,\infty]$ although $\lambda$ is a set function and its domain should be a subset of $\mathcal P(X)$ and domain of $\mu$ is not given ,so we do not know whether $E\cap A$ is $\mu$-measurable so that the right hand side makes sense.So,can someone correct the question and tell me what should have been the right question?

Comment: I suppose it was intended that $A$ be measurable.

Comment: @user940160 Still $E\cap A$ need not be measurable

Comment: yes, the domain of $\lambda$ must be as you write above. You may assume there is a sigma-algebra present. This is usually assumed as soon as you read "mu is measure on X"

Comment: @311411 Should I assume that the domain of $\lambda$ is the whole of $\mathcal P(X)$?

Comment: No the domain should consist of measurable sets. Then it is also clear that $A\cap E$ is measurable

Comment: I would assume that $\lambda$ is defined on the same $\sigma$-algebra as $\mu$. That along with the assumption that $A$ is measureable make $\lambda$ a measure.

Comment: Alternatively as you said this was a question we could simply say that $\lambda$ is ill defined and so cannot be a measure as our answer.

Comment: I do not think it is essential to assume that A is measurable with respect to the measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$

Comment: @311411 It is definitely nessesary as if $E=X$ then $\lambda(E)=\mu(A)$

Comment: Fishbane, you are correct. I was thinking of the different construction involving outer measure: given $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and $D\subset X$ (arbitrary), we have the measure space $(D,\Sigma_D,\mu^{*}{\mid}_{\Sigma_D})$

Comment: Please use the word doubt correctly. İt has meaning only for some specific regions.